# How resize layout after known the size of screen width

Tags: android, resize, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to change the size of a relative layout (and a ImageView inside of it) after known the size of the screen to make a perfect square as a layout, but I'm doing something wrong.

Could someone give me a hand with this?

I'm getting the size with:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

rl_camera = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rl_camera);
iv_thumbnail = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)rl_camera.getLayoutParams();
params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
rl_camera.setLayoutParams(params);

iv_thumbnail.setMinimumHeight(metrics.heightPixels);

rl_camera.invalidate();
iv_thumbnail.invalidate();
```

The app crashes with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams...
```

on the line:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)rl_camera.getLayoutParams();
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
        android:text="@string/IMPORTE_TITLE_STRING"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ll_amount"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/etAmount"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:minWidth="128dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/IMPORTE_PLACEHOLDER_STRING"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:text="@string/euro_symbol"
            android:id="@+id/tvEuroSymbol"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl_camera"
        android:background="@color/app_disable">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FOTO_TICKET_STRING"
            android:id="@+id/tvCameraInfo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_zoomed"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: The type of `LayoutParams` a `View` has depends on its parent `View`, not what it itself is. Your `RelativeLayout` is in a `LinearLayout`, and so has `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 1):

change the Top most LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. Also to make the camera view below the inner layout, use layout_below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
    android:text="@string/IMPORTE_TITLE_STRING"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_margin="16dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ll_amount"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:id="@+id/etAmount"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_normal"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:minWidth="128dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/IMPORTE_PLACEHOLDER_STRING"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:text="@string/euro_symbol"
        android:id="@+id/tvEuroSymbol"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:id="@+id/rl_camera"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_amount"
    android:background="@color/app_disable">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/FOTO_TICKET_STRING"
        android:id="@+id/tvCameraInfo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/iv_zoomed"
    android:layout_below="@id/rl_camera"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace last lines of your code with these:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)rl_camera.getLayoutParams(); 
params.height = metrics.heightPixels; 
params.width = params.height; // to shape the layout as a square
rl_camera.setLayoutParams(params);
rl_camera.requestLayout();
```